# Iterate over a fetch call with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to convert a while of a fetch of data in PDO into a for loop.
The for loop don't have to be a foreach but something like that:

```
for($count = 0; .........; $count++){}
```

How can i do that? My code now is:

```
while ($row = $stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    print("<tr>");
    print("<td>".$row['name']."</td>");
    print("<td>".$row['surname']."</td>");
    print("<td>".$row['dateOfBirth']."</td>");
    print("</tr>");
}
```

Comment: You can add count into your while

Comment: @splash58 i need to get the next element and insert an if i don't know how to do that so i thought it was better do a for loop

Comment: If you need to know the number of rows, you can use `$stmt->rowCount()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd parameter in a `for` loop is the condition under which the loop should be executed, which is

```
$index < $stmt->rowCount()
```

Official Reference:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

So the code is

```
for ($index=0; $index < $stmt->rowCount(); $index++){

$row = $stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

 print("<tr>");
    print("<td>".$row['name']."</td>");
    print("<td>".$row['surname']."</td>");
    print("<td>".$row['dateOfBirth']."</td>");
    print("</tr>");

}
```